# How come lexical value of this is retained without "Arrow" function: ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I [have created a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tSbnPwVpulG40rs6Bnhf?p=preview), as you can see I have called the functions once from `$scope.init` which works as expected where as when I create a separate

```
function exec(){
  this.data = "234"
    function es5(){
      console.log(this.data) //<-- Has access ?
    }
    es5();
    es6 = () => {
      console.log(this.data)
    }
    es6();
}
```

and called it from `$scope.init`, the function has access to `this`

Take a look at `console` of browser once the plunker is loaded

Comment: Because you didn't implicitly bind function `es5`, it is default binded and gets parent scope as `this` value.

Comment: @nrgwsth : ok, but how is it is not getting binded in case of `init` function ?

Comment: `this` inside `es5` is `window`. If `window.data` is anything useful, that's because you have set something to `window.data` before, probably using the same technique. E.g., if you execute `exec` as just `exec()`, `this` inside `exec` is `window` as well.

Comment: Please show us how `exec` is called. If you just do `exec()` like you did `es5()`, their `this` is indeed the same thing. Also, always use strict mode!